# Put previous row values in a cell of DataFrame and use certain condition to change values

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

As of now I want to change the values which are true in the column 'Over_ball' with previous row value
but get an error using this code below.

[image: X.jpg]

#Code

```
for row in range(0,len(df_3)):
df_3['Over_ball'] = df_3['Over_ball'].replace('True',df_3['Over_ball'].shift(1))
```

#Error

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<input>", line 2, in <module>
 File "C:\Python 3.9\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 4479, in replace
 return super().replace(
 File "C:\Python 3.9\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 6918, in replace
 raise ValueError( ValueError: Series.replace cannot use dict-value and non-None to_replace
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So long as the first row doesn't contain a True value, You can use the following:

```
for row in range(1, df.shape[0]):
    if df.loc[row,'Over_ball'] == True:
        df.loc[row,'Over_ball'] = df.loc[row-1,'Over_ball']
```

Comment: that solved my problem many many thanx but what do you mean by the condition you wrote about 1st row not containing a True value can you please explain me the scenario...

Comment: If the first row contains a True value in 'Over_ball' column, there is no previous row from which to draw a value.  That is why, I started my search from row 1, so I could always rely on the fact that a prior row exists.